# When sending to the server with APE, it gives this message: I/AssistStructure (9867): Flattened final assist data: 816 bytes, containing 1 windows,

Tags: flutter-getx

I want to send API to the PHP server with Get, but it gives this message and does not connect. While it was working before, this problem has occurred after forever.

```
  Future<void> checkLogIn() async {
    String validateEmail(String val) {
      if (val.isEmpty) {
        return "Email cannot be empty";
      } else if (!EmailValidator.validate(val, true)) {
        return "Invalid Email Address";
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    }

    String email = emailController.text;
    String error = validateEmail(email);

    if (error != "") {
      Get.snackbar("Warning", "Invalid email format",
          backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent);
      return;
    } else if (emailController.text.isEmpty) {
      Get.snackbar("Warning", "Email is required",
          backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent);
      return;
    } else if (passController.text.isEmpty) {
      Get.snackbar("Warning", "Password is required",
          backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent);
      return;
    } else if (passController.text.length > 31) {
      Get.snackbar("Warning", "You can enter up to 31 characters",
          backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent);
      return;
    } else {
      // اعتبارسنجی صحیح است، ادامه عملیات

      /*
      if (ModelUser.isConnected) {
        Get.snackbar('Error', 'No internet connection',
            backgroundColor: Colors.red);
        return;
      }
*/

      Get.showOverlay(
        asyncFunction: () => login(),
        loadingWidget: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );

    }
  }

  Future<ModelUser?> login() async {
    var url = Uri.parse("http://localhost/advertising/login.php");

   try {
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Charset': 'utf-8'},
        body: jsonEncode(
          {
            "email": emailController.text,
            "password": passController.text,
          },
        ),
      );

      if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 392.72727272727275) {
        print(response.statusCode);
        ModelUser.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        Get.snackbar('Success', 'Login Successfully',
            backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent);
        Get.off(
          () => Get.to(Responsive(
            desktop: const MainScreen(),
            tablet: Table(),
            mobile: const Mobile(),
          )),
        );
      } else {
        Get.snackbar(
          'Failed',
          'Login failed',
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        );
      }
   } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
        'Error',
        'Failed to connect to the server',
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      );
    }
return null;


  }
/*
  Future<bool> checkInternetConnectivity() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }
*/

}
```

After sending the request, it gives the message that Failed to connect to the server and this message is also displayed in the terminal. I/AssistStructure (9867): Flattened final assist data: 816 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views. Also, the code status is I/flutter (9867): 392.72727272727275

[image]